# What is the difference between “container_memory_working_set_bytes” and “container_memory_rss” metric on the container

Tags: kubernetes, memory, containers, monitoring

I need to monitor my container memory usage running on kubernetes cluster. After read some  articles there're two recommendations: `container_memory_rss`, `container_memory_working_set_bytes`

The definitions of both metrics are said (from the cAdvisor code)

- `container_memory_rss` : The amount of anonymous and swap cache memory
- `container_memory_working_set_bytes`: The amount of working set memory, this includes recently accessed memory, dirty memory, and kernel memory

I think both metrics are represent the bytes size on the physical memory that process uses. But there are some differences between the two values from my Grafana dashboard.

**My question is:**

- What is the difference between two metrics?
- Which metrics are much proper to monitor memory usage? Some post said both because one of those metrics reaches to the limit, then that container is OOM killed.

Comment: I belive this one addresses your question. https://github.com/google/cadvisor/issues/2582#issuecomment-644883028

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You are right. I will try to address your questions in more detail.

> What is the difference between two metrics?

`container_memory_rss` equals to the value of `total_rss` from `/sys/fs/cgroups/memory/memory.status` file:

```
// The amount of anonymous and swap cache memory (includes transparent
// hugepages).
// Units: Bytes.
RSS uint64 `json:"rss"`
```

The total amount of anonymous and swap cache memory (it includes transparent hugepages), and it equals to the value of `total_rss` from `memory.status` file. This should not be confused with the true `resident set size` or the amount of physical memory used by the cgroup. `rss + file_mapped` will give you the resident set size of cgroup. It does not include memory that is swapped out. It does include memory from shared libraries as long as the pages from those libraries are actually in memory. It does include all stack and heap memory.

---

`container_memory_working_set_bytes` (as already mentioned by Olesya) is the `total usage` - `inactive file`. It is an estimate of how much memory cannot be evicted:

```
// The amount of working set memory, this includes recently accessed memory,
// dirty memory, and kernel memory. Working set is <= "usage".
// Units: Bytes.
WorkingSet uint64 `json:"working_set"`
```

Working Set is the current size, in bytes, of the Working Set of this process. The Working Set is the set of memory pages touched recently by the threads in the process.

---

> Which metrics are much proper to monitor memory usage? Some post said
> both because one of those metrics reaches to the limit, then that
> container is oom killed.

If you are [limiting the resource usage](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/) for your pods than you should monitor both as they will cause an oom-kill if they reach a particular resource limit.

I also recommend [this article](https://faun.pub/how-much-is-too-much-the-linux-oomkiller-and-used-memory-d32186f29c9d) which shows an example explaining the below assertion:

> You might think that memory utilization is easily tracked with
> `container_memory_usage_bytes`, however, this metric also includes
> cached (think filesystem cache) items that can be evicted under memory
> pressure. The better metric is `container_memory_working_set_bytes` as
> this is what the OOM killer is watching for.

**EDIT:**

Adding some additional sources as a supplement:

- [A Deep Dive into Kubernetes Metrics — Part 3 Container Resource Metrics](https://blog.freshtracks.io/a-deep-dive-into-kubernetes-metrics-part-3-container-resource-metrics-361c5ee46e66)
- [#1744](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/issues/1744)
- [Understanding Kubernetes Memory Metrics](https://www.magalix.com/blog/memory_working_set-vs-memory_rss)
- [Memory_working_set vs Memory_rss in Kubernetes, which one you should monitor?](https://medium.com/@eng.mohamed.m.saeed/memory-working-set-vs-memory-rss-in-kubernetes-which-one-you-should-monitor-8ef77bf0acee)
- [Managing Resources for Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/)
- [cAdvisor code](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/50b23f4ed9bc53cf068316b67bee04c4145f1e73/info/v1/container.go#L379)

Comment: I posted [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66832316/what-is-the-relation-between-container-memory-working-set-bytes-metric-and-oom) related with this. Could you also review that?

Comment: I just did. Feel free to take a look.

Comment: I have a similar question I feel the answer does not clearly distinguish the relation on container_memory_rss and container_memory_working_set since in my case the working_set is 10 times more than container_memory_rss. Also, the OP question has a comment has a GitHub link that states working_set does not include inactive_file (so no swap cache?) which is again does not explain why rss is so low compared to working_set since rss include swap cache as well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68289644/relationship-between-container-memory-working-set-bytes-and-process-resident-mem

Answer (score 9):

Actually **this is not an answer, but as an enhancement to the accepted answer**. And the following comments apply to cgroup v1, might be not applicable to cgroup v2.

> `container_memory_working_set_bytes` (as already mentioned by Olesya) is the `total usage` - `inactive file`. It is an estimate of how much memory cannot be evicted:

The first sentence is true, but the *cannot be evicted* comment **is not true**: at least, `container_memory_working_set_bytes` includes the value presented by `total_active_file`, which can be evicted by:

1. system auto reclaiming due to low available memory
2. `echo 1/2/3 > drop_caches` mentioned by [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/43916), and see [this link](https://linux-mm.org/Drop_Caches) for the meaning of the values 1/2/3
3. `echo 0 > memory.force_empty` mentioned by the [cgroup doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/memory.txt), section 5.1

And as a result, the following conclusion might be also not true:

> If you are limiting the resource usage for your pods than you should monitor both as they will cause an oom-kill if they reach a particular resource limit.

`container_memory_working_set_bytes` reaching the limit actually may not lead to an oom-kill, at least it didn't get an oom-kill in our environment. In our environment, we monitored that `total_active_file` kept increasing and thus `container_memory_working_set_bytes` kept increasing, after `container_memory_working_set_bytes` reached the limit, `total_active_file` dropped to a lower value due to memory reclaiming and thus `container_memory_working_set_bytes` also dropped to a lower value, the pod was running all the time without been killed.

Actually there are already two issues ([this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/43916) and [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/104533)) about the `container_memory_working_set_bytes` metric, however, none of them are solved. In our environment, we are now monitoring `container_memory_rss` instead of `container_memory_working_set_bytes` due to the false alert mentioned above.