# What is the relation between `container_memory_working_set_bytes` metric and OOM-killer on the container?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, memory, containers

I'm trying to find out and understand how OOM-killer works on the container.

To figuring it out, I've read lots of articles and I found out that OOM-killer kills container  based on the `oom_score`. And `oom_score` is determined by `oom_score_adj` and memory usage of that process.

And there're two metrics `container_memory_working_set_bytes`, `container_memory_rss` from the cAdvisor for monitoring memory usage of the container.

It seems that RSS memory (`container_memory_rss`) has impact on `oom_score` so I can understand that with the `container_memory_rss` metric, if that metric reached to memory limit, the OOM-killer will kill the process.

- https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v3.10/fs/proc/base.c#L439
- https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v3.10/mm/oom_kill.c#L141
- https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v3.10/include/linux/mm.h#L1136

But from the articles like below:

- https://faun.pub/how-much-is-too-much-the-linux-oomkiller-and-used-memory-d32186f29c9d
- https://blog.freshtracks.io/a-deep-dive-into-kubernetes-metrics-part-3-container-resource-metrics-361c5ee46e66

> The better metric is `container_memory_working_set_bytes` as this is what the OOM killer is watching for.

**I cannot understand the fact that OOM-killer is watching for container's working set memory.** I think I'm not understand the meaning of the working set memory on the container which is 'total usage - inactive file'.

- https://github.com/google/cadvisor/issues/2582#issuecomment-644883028

Where can I find the reference? Or could you explain the relationship between working set memory and OOM-kill on the container?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you already know, `container_memory_working_set_bytes` is:

> the amount of working set memory and it includes recently accessed
> memory, dirty memory, and kernel memory. Therefore, Working set is
> (lesser than or equal to) </= "usage".

The `container_memory_working_set_bytes` is being used for OoM decisions because it **excludes cached data** ([Linux Page Cache](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Linux_Page_Cache_Basics)) that can be evicted in memory pressure scenarios.

So, if the `container_memory_working_set_bytes` is increased to the limit, it will lead to oomkill.

You can find the fact that when Linux kernel checking available memory, it calls [`vm_enough_memory()`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/mm/util.c#L872) to find out how many pages are potentially available.

Then when the machine is low on memory, old page frames including cache will be reclaimed but kernel still may find that it was unable free enough pages to satisfy a request. Now it's time to call [`out_of_memory()`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/mm/oom_kill.c#L1048) to kill the process. To determine the candidate process to be killed it uses `oom_score`.

So when Working Set bytes reached to limits, it means that kernel cannot find availables pages even after reclaiming old pages including cache so kernel will trigger OOM-killer to kill the process.

You can find more details on the Linux kernel documents:

- https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand016.html
- https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand013.html

Comment: I just append the details of how kernel trigger OOM-killer and added kernel docs links.