# relationship between container_memory_working_set_bytes and process_resident_memory_bytes and total_rss

Tags: go, kubernetes, cgroups, cadvisor, kubernetes-metrics

I'm looking to understanding the relationship of

**container_memory_working_set_bytes** vs **process_resident_memory_bytes** vs **total_rss** (container_memory_rss) + **file_mapped** so as to better equipped system for alerting on OOM possibility.

[image]

It seems against my understanding (which is puzzling me right now) given **if a container/pod is running a single process executing a compiled program written in Go.**

Why is the difference between `container_memory_working_set_bytes` is so big(nearly 10 times more) with respect to `process_resident_memory_bytes`

Also the relationship between `container_memory_working_set_bytes` and `container_memory_rss + file_mapped` is weird here, something I did not expect, after reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65428558/what-is-the-difference-between-container-memory-working-set-bytes-and-contain)

> The total amount of anonymous and swap cache memory (it includes transparent hugepages), and it equals to the value of total_rss from memory.status file. This should not be confused with the true resident set size or the amount of physical memory used by the cgroup. rss + file_mapped will give you the resident set size of cgroup. It does not include memory that is swapped out. It does include memory from shared libraries as long as the pages from those libraries are actually in memory. It does include all stack and heap memory.

So `cgroup` total resident set size is `rss + file_mapped` how does this value is less than `container_working_set_bytes` for a container that is running in the given cgroup

Which make me feels something with this stats that I'm not correct.

Following are the PROMQL used to build the above graph

- process_resident_memory_bytes{container="sftp-downloader"}
- container_memory_working_set_bytes{container="sftp-downloader"}
- go_memstats_heap_alloc_bytes{container="sftp-downloader"}
- container_memory_mapped_file{container="sftp-downloader"} + container_memory_rss{container="sftp-downloader"}

Comment: how about go_memstats_heap_inuse_bytes? container_memory_working_set_bytes is more trustworthy metric anyway.

Comment: Agreeed but the people are referring to watch for container_memory_rss and working_set both for OOM kill. And the underline think I intend to understand the relationship of rss vs working_set

Comment: FYI, https://medium.com/@eng.mohamed.m.saeed/memory-working-set-vs-memory-rss-in-kubernetes-which-one-you-should-monitor-8ef77bf0acee

Comment: Seen that not useful in term of what question I'm looking

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So the relationship seems is like this

```
container_working_set_in_bytes = container_memory_usage_bytes - total_inactive_file
```

`container_memory_usage_bytes` as its name implies means the total memory used by the container (but since it also includes file cache i.e inactive_file which OS can release under memory pressure) substracting the inactive_file gives `container_working_set_in_bytes`

Relationship between `container_memory_rss` and `container_working_sets` can be summed up using following expression

```
container_memory_usage_bytes = container_memory_cache + container_memory_rss
```

cache reflects data stored on a disk that is currently cached in memory. it contains active + inactive file (mentioned above)

This explains why the `container_working_set` was higher.

Ref [#1](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/how-to-monitor-docker-resource-metrics/#memory)

Ref [#2](https://www.docker.com/blog/gathering-lxc-docker-containers-metrics/#memory-metrics)

Comment: Not sure if I am reading the equations incorrectly, but it seems that the equations could be reformatted as

`container_working_set_bytes = container_memory_rss + total_active_file`

`container_memory_usage_bytes = container_memory_rss + total_inactive_file + total_active_file`

Which means, `conaainer_working_set_bytes` should always be smaller than `container_memory_usage_bytes`.

Comment: Yes, correct. Since container_memory_usage_bytes also include caches in a nutshell container_working_set_bytes is what RSS in real term

Comment: @bluefog it seems like you missed container_memory_swap and kernel memory in your equations. As I understand this, container_working_set_bytes = container_memory_rss + total_active_file + container_memory_swap + kernel memory and container_memory_usage_bytes = container_memory_rss + total_inactive_file + total_active_file + container_memory_swap + kernel memory

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but still two assorted points.

Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66778814/720999) help to make sense of the chart?

Here at my $dayjob, we had faced various different issues with how different tools *external to the Go runtime* count and display memory usage of a process executing a program written in Go.
Coupled with the fact Go's GC on Linux does not actually release freed memory pages to the kernel but merely [`madvise(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/2/madvise)s it that such pages are `MADV_FREE`, a GC cycle which had freed quite a hefty amount of memory does not result in any noticeable change of the readings of the "process' RSS" taken by the external tooling (usually `cgroups` stats).

Hence we're exporting our own metrics obtained by periodically calling [`runtime.ReadMemStats`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#ReadMemStats) (and `runtime/debug.ReadGCStats`) in any major serivice written in Go — with the help of a simple package written specifically for that. These readings reflect the true idea of the Go runtime about the memory under its control.

By the way, the `NextGC` field of the memory stats is super useful to watch if you have memory limits set for your containers because once that reading reaches or surpasses your memory limit, the process in the container is surely doomed to be eventually shot down by the oom_killer.

Comment: Well based on that article I thought container_memory_rss + mapped_file would be the true RSS of the `cgroup` which I assumed to higher than `container_memory_working_set_bytes` but actually, it was not.

Comment: Also if I'm correct golang 1.16 drop support for madvice.

Comment: @Noobie, no, it uses another flag with `madvise(2)`: [`MADV_DONTNEED` instead of `MADV_FREE`](https://golang.org/doc/go1.16#runtime) — essentially reverting the behaviour [introduced in Go 1.12](https://golang.org/doc/go1.12#runtime). Unfortunately the [man page](https://manpages.debian.org/2/madvise) is not crystal clear on what happens to the observable RSS reading of a process which marked a page with `madvise(MADV_DONTNEED)`.

Comment: If I reading it correct it states this `On Linux, the runtime now defaults to releasing memory to the operating system promptly (using MADV_DONTNEED), rather than lazily when the operating system is under memory pressure (using MADV_FREE)`. **This means process-level memory statistics like RSS will more accurately reflect the amount of physical memory being used by Go processes** and `The resident set size (RSS) of the calling process will be immediately reduced`
              however.`