# Why I get the different metrics values using kubectl and prometheus?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, promql

I need to measure and show to the user current k8s resource usage of the k8s pods. We gather metrics by using prometheus. I tried to compare the data which I get by using `kubectl top` command and prometheus query but get the different results, why?

To get metrics by using **kubectl** I'm using the following command:

```bash
kubectl top pod -n your-namespace --no-headers | awk '{cpu+=$2; memory+=$3} END {print "CPU: " cpu "m, Memory: " memory "Mi"}'
```

basically it get results from the all pods which related to specific namespace, sum it and return. When I run it for specific namespace I get the following value:

> CPU: 3m, Memory: 1137Mi

But when I run the following query in Prometheus:

```
sum (container_memory_working_set_bytes{namespace="<same_namespace_as_above>"}) by (pod_name)
```

I get 2.33Gb

According to [conversion calculator](https://www.gbmb.org/mib-to-mb):

> 1137 MiB = 1192.230912 MB

The difference is huge and there's no correlation at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65428558/what-is-the-difference-between-container-memory-working-set-bytes-and-contain)?